# Public static void in ConsoleApplication

Tags: c#, console-application

i doing firstime consoleapplication. I have WinformApp, and i copy code to ConsoleApp.
I have problem, i don´t know how could i jump from static void Main to public static void Sending. This is SAMPLE of my code...

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter; //Counter pro export
        int counterchyba;
        string strediska = "0003,0005";                                   
    }

    public static void Sending(int counter, int counterchyba, string strediska)
    {
        var c = (counter).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        .........
    }
}
```

Have you any idea how could it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the main function you can call the code of sending like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter; //Counter pro export
        int counterchyba;
        string strediska = "0003,0005"; 
        Sending(0, 0, strediska);                
    }

    public static void Sending(int counter, int counterchyba, string strediska)
    {
        var c = (counter).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        .........
    }
 }
```

however, i don't know what the point of `Sending` function parameters: `counter`, `counterchyba` and `strediska` so you need to figure out what to put in them

**One more important thing:**

you said this is a consoleapplication and that you started a WinformApp. don't do it, it will end in problems that will take days to solve. start a new solution, a console application.

Answer (score 6):

In your `Main` you can literally just call `Sending(counter, counterchyba, strediska);`

Main is where it all starts. You can initiate any actions from there.

Comment: Note that if the method Sending was **not** declared as `static`, OP would have to create an instance of the program to call it - i.e., `Program prg = new Program(); prg.Sending(Sending(counter, counterchyba, strediska);`

Comment: indeed but that'd be a different question ;-)

Comment: @Paul Farry: Yes, i Try it...but i have this errors: Use of unassigned local variable 'counter'..same problem with counter and counterchyba...:/

Comment: @PaulFarry - Since OP is new to programming, I think there would be value in pointing out the difference.

Comment: Variables inside a method are not automatically assigned a default value. You need to assign it, for example: `int counter = 0; int counterchyba = 0;`